# What does the shape predictor do

Tags: dlib

What exactly does the shape_predictor predict in http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp.html ? I read it, but i don't understand. I want make a dataset of average landmarks of a Person. Should I take the facelandmark-detection of dlib instead and extract the landmarks and then calc a average landmark by hand?

Answer (score 1):

train_shape_predictor_ex example has a lot of comments inside it. you should read it first.
Shortely - it make shape predictor training process that will make new shape predictor model for any kind of object. Shape predictor can work as for faces, as for any kind of objects - signs, letters, forms, cars... And training process will make data model for it

As I understand, you have some images with person face and you need to get average landmarks for this person. In this case, you do not need any training - you can run shape_predictor with pre-trained model on them and calculate averages manually